# jquery dark mode on html page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, user-interface

I have a program with `example.html` doing the following:

```
 <body>
...
    <!-- Light mode and dark mode -->
    <div>
      <nav>
        <img src="images/dark-mode.png" id="icon">
      </nav>
   </div>
...
</body>
```

Here is `example.css`

```
:root{
    --primary-color: #c2aaba;
    --secondary-color: linear-gradient(315deg, #d9e4f5 0%, #f5e3e6 74%); 
}

.dark-theme{
    --primary-color: #181818;
    --secondary-color: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(168,120,132,1) 0%, rgba(194,170,186,1) 54%, rgba(241,241,241,1) 100%);; 
}
#icon {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 10px;
    right: 20px;
    width: 30px;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Inconsolata', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  background: var(--primary-color);
}
```

My `example.js` file looks like:

```
$(function() {
    ///
    var icon = document.getElementById("icon");
    $(#icon).on("click", function() {
        document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
    });
});
```

I am using `jQuery` for other parts of this page, however, I am not sure what is wrong with the code.

`dark-mode.png` is an icon which when clicked on, changes the colors on the page accordingly.
However, my program is doing nothing right now.

Comment: If you want to set the `onclick` property, it should be `icon.onclick = function(){}`.

Comment: But why don't you just use jQuery there if you're already using it on the page? `$('#icon').click(function(){})`

Comment: @Unmitigated Thank you for the suggestion! I am new to jQuery so didn't even think of doing that. I have changed it now, but the program still isn't working. Does everything else look alright?

Comment: It's working fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/tnL7ra1f/

Comment: The only other change I made was to remove `///` (which is invalid syntax) in the CSS.

Comment: Ah yes - sorry that was a typo for this post, it doesn't exist in the actual code @Unmitigated

Comment: Regardless, it's working with the code in your post: https://jsfiddle.net/tnL7ra1f/

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct and working code:

```
$(function() {
     $("#icon").on("click", function() {
         document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
     });
});
```

Basically the only mistake you made is that you didn't use quotes when specifying the selector